# Multiple operators between operands

Tags: python

Can someone explain why the Python interpreter (2.7.3) gives the following:

```
>>> 5 -+-+-+ 2

3
```

Is this ever useful, and for what purpose?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You  can use `dis` here to see how the expression was actually evaluated:

```
In [29]: def func():
   ....:     return 5 -+-+-+ 2
   ....: 

In [30]: import dis

In [31]: dis.dis(func)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (5)
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              6 UNARY_POSITIVE      
              7 UNARY_NEGATIVE      
              8 UNARY_POSITIVE      
              9 UNARY_NEGATIVE      
             10 UNARY_POSITIVE      
             11 BINARY_SUBTRACT     
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

So that expression is equivalent to this:

```
In [32]: 5 - (+(-(+(-(+(2))))))
Out[32]: 3
```

Comment: You can `dis` lambdas: `dis.dis(lambda: 5 -+-+-+ 2)`

Answer (score 6):

This is just equal to

```
5 - (+(-(+(-(+2)))))
```

where all the + and - beyond the first are unary operators. For numbers, `+` returns the operand unchanged. But, its meaning can be overridden using the `__pos__` special method on your own classes.

It's useless obfuscation to do this with numbers, but it may be useful (if incredibly confusing) if you are using class instances with custom `__neg__` and/or `__pos__` operations.

---

You can abuse this to get C-like pre-increment `--` and `++` operators. Don't ever actually do this.

```
class IncrementableInteger(object):
    def __init__(self, val=0):
        self.val = val
    def __pos__(self):
        class PlusOne:
            def __pos__(_self):
                self.val += 1
        return PlusOne()
    def __neg__(self):
        class MinusOne:
            def __neg__(_self):
                self.val -= 1
        return MinusOne()
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.val)
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.val)
```

Example:

```
>>> IncrementableInteger(4)
4
>>> v=_
>>> ++v
>>> v
5
```

Comment: So, other than obfuscation it really is useless?

Comment: @AthomSfere: Well, if you like doing `++x` in C, you can now do it in Python! (Very much not recommended for actual code besides amusement potential)

Comment: Ah, but ++x vs x++ does have a very specific function (Although mostly redundant!) I like your explanation, but it really does seem to be more of a puzzle / obfuscating practice than a practical logic exercise. And I take it never do this for any real code?!

Comment: Of course. Use common sense -- if it's going to be confusing to understand, it's probably the wrong approach.

Answer (score 3):

Other than obfuscate the code, I don't see any utility to this.

The evaluation of this is:

```
5 -+-+-+ 2 = 5 -(+(-(+(-(+ 2)))))
           = 5 -(+(-(+(- 2))))
           = 5 -(+(-(- 2)))
           = 5 -(+(+ 2))
           = 5 -(+ 2)
           = 5 - 2
           = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

It is interpreted like this:

```
5 - (+(-(+(-(+2)))))
```

You are allowed to write `-a` to get the negative of `a`. For symmetry and "Why not?" you are also to use a plus sign prefix like `+a`.

Adding multiple signs isn't really useful, but it is allowed, probably because it just happens to be legal in the grammar and nobody saw a need to explicitly forbid it.